# UbuntuGnome XPS 13 (9434) WiFi Issues

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, xps

I recently purchased the new XPS 13 2015. I have managed to get nearly everything to work with various fixes but the WiFi is not one of those issues. After installing the bcm-kernel-source driver the wifi kind of works. It is painfully slow and barely usable, if I use an external wifi card the problem instantly goes away.

I don't know how much truth there is to this, but this guy in the comments on this site seems to have gotten his Brodcam wifi card working out of the box somehow:
https://major.io/2015/02/03/linux-support-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-model/

Here is some information about my wifi setup:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e75793a552468f06ce2

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using the Additional Software tab in the Software & Updates Settings section to automatically find and install driver software for the WiFi driver?

Comment: @Ads20000 Nope, installing it that way does the same thing. It's still really slow.

Comment: Maybe report a bug with `ubuntu-bug bcm-kernel-source`? Idk, is that the open-source one?

Comment: It has been reported back in 2013 and never fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173761

Comment: Ah cool, well done for finding that, in the bug report is a workaround, use that :) use it (download and install the older driver recommended) and, if it works, write that as an answer and accept it when it lets you for rep :) (doing that is allowed and encouraged!)

Comment: @Ads20000 I did try the old driver, unfortunately it doesn't work on 15.04 anymore. It just instantly crashes and ubuntu tells me that a program stopped working. :/

Comment: Ah well, the thing about bugs that aren't fixed is that they're bugs that aren't fixed. Sounds like you'll just have to use the external WiFi card sorry.

Comment: @Ads2000 Well I was hoping that there is some other solution, the reason for this being is that dell says that this should work properly. They are still fixing some other issues but they say that to get the wifi to work you don't need any additional patches and it should actually work out of the box. People have even reported to get it working out of the box, it seems strange my case is different when using the same model.